# Pandas DataFrame: Creating 3D Surface Plots

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, 3d, surface

I am trying to draw a 3D surface plot using 3 columns (3 features) in a data frame:

```
age size_tc Survival_days
0   60.463  43185.0 289
1   52.263  15709.0 616
2   54.301  3731.0  464
3   39.068  26400.0 788
4   68.493  14410.0 465
5   67.126  44774.0 269
6   69.912  9557.0  503
7   56.419  76260.0 1155
8   48.367  6994.0  515
9   65.899  8280.0  495
10  59.693  14535.0 698
11  51.734  27568.0 359
12  62.614  17677.0 169
13  55.759  41082.0 368
14  58.258  14713.0 439
15  61.605  2036.0  486
16  68.049  20547.0 287
17  56.921  5669.0  576
18  44.162  30637.0 350
19  67.833  17526.0 332
20  46.666  28472.0 331
21  76.367  15027.0 106
22  67.860  24355.0 473
23  46.452  44985.0 1283
24  71.370  5751.0  89
25  75.978  24963.0 172
26  53.362  19018.0 84
27  75.312  40795.0 726
28  46.570  3461.0  660
29  77.337  7635.0  522
```

My code is as follows:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = df['age']
y =  df['size_tc']
z = df['survival']

surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap= cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0.2)
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

Why the plot is not smooth and how can I generate a plot like this?

[image]

Comment: Could you share a sample of the data?

Comment: I edited the question and included a sample of the data.

Comment: Can you add more data points? Like, upload a sample file with 30 or more points as CSV. Having 5 points isn't sufficient.

Comment: I edited the question again with 30 data points.

Comment: After looking into it, it seems that your data doesn't represent any continuous function. You can cluster the points but you can't be smoothing it using surface smoothing. https://imgur.com/a/MEoyigd